# Google Maps startActivityForResult

Tags: android, google-maps

I would like to start a Maps activity and get back a location result. Is this doable without using a MapView and having to require the google maps library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
you should add "onclick" event listener to your map. It will return coords when event is fired.
Please find more details in map API documentation. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html

Comment: very interesting! are you suggesting using a WebView in which I embed a MapView? and then have some callbacks from javascript into java?

Comment: did this solution work? Could you provide more details? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You know the Geo position / name of the location. You can get the location information using Google Maps Web Service API.

Pleas look into the following link  for details. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/

If you are sure about getting location information from Map Acitivity, You cant achieve it without using MapView.

PS: Other Suggestion is You can have it a static map and respective location matrix if the map area is well defined.

Comment: No, I don't know the location. I want to let the user choose any point on the map and return it to my activity.